# What does the punctuation "//" mean?

Tags: punctuation, programming

What does the punctuation "//" mean? For example:

> I think I owe myself a THWACK.
> //ashamed
>
> ... //run
>
> ... //head down

I heard this is related to the comment in the programming language C. But still I don't get the actual meaning and purpose it tries to convey, not to say how to use "//".

Is such usage of "//" informal?

Comment: The excellent answers forget to say that this is *very* informal.

Comment: This basically not an answer, but I use double-slashes as an abbreviation for "Best regards… best wishes… truly yours etc."
//Otto

Comment: In Everquest, the first really popular MMORPG in the US, an emote was typed as **/wave** or **/bow** or similar, and the avatar would enact it on screen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`//` comes from programming and is generally used to denote a comment or explanation that should be ignored by the compiler or computer. Its purpose is to leave notes and instructions for future programmers or anyone else that needs to understand what is happening in code. The literary equivalent is a footnote.

In the examples you provide, the words following the `//` are comments of emotions or actions to let the reader know what the author was feeling or doing.

> I think I owe myself a THWACK. //ashamed

This means that whoever said this was ashamed of their actions. Similar constructions include using `:emotion:` or an emoticon:

> Yeah, that is great idea. :eyeroll:
>
> This is great news! :)

Other programming style behaviors include `^H` and nested or malformed `( ) [ ] { }` pairs:

> I will stalk^H^H^H^H^Hfollow you everywhere!
>
> I like pizza (with olives (except green olives (but you can put them on your half of the pizza))).

Comment: Backspacing a character requires sending a control code instead of a printable character. The key-combination CTRL+H or a key that was set up to duplicate that combination would send that control code. Some environments would echo (display) that 'non-printable' code instead of acting on the command. ^ indicates the CTRL key. Thus, when you attempted to backspace something, you sometimes saw a sequence of ^H displayed to the screen. A Google search for CTRL <letter> will turn up a variety of control codes with much better explanations than I could possibly provide.

Comment: In addition to what @Ron said, here is the [relevant Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%5EH)

Comment: Also the use of sarcasm or irony HTML tags. <sarcasm>Not that any self-respecting dev would do that.</sarcasm>

Answer (score 7):

I know this is not relevant to your case, but a single or double slash is also used when citing poetry, to indicate where the metre or line ends in a continuous quotation: *at regina gravi iamdudum saucia cura // vulnus alit venis et caeco carpitur igni.* It looks like this in proper print:

> At regina gravi iamdudum saucia cura
>
> Vulnus alit venis et caeco carpitur
>   igni

Comment: It's very relevant if you post software-related haiku to Twitter. You might think that unlikely, yet given the overlap on this site...

Comment: @Lunivore: Right, I suppose anything can be a poem! But what if you are quoting from a poem that spans several lines and also includes // from code comments...

Comment: Then it would be in perl, and use #, not //. http://www.tamias.net/rjk/perl/poetry/

Answer (score 3):

It is very informal, looks like a variant of an [emote](http://www.wowwiki.com/Emote) which uses a singular slash, the double is probably influenced by programming comments, but hard to say.  Particularly as a double slash in written work usually means "new line here".

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, a double slash `//` is often used to denote where a new paragraph or line should have started.

This is often common in schoolwork, where students may realise they should have started a new paragraph after-the-fact, and must add it in later without re-writing a significant portion of their work.